# Multithread program in C++: Using mutex on a flag variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am currently working on a multithreaded code in c++ in which each thread is set to execute a piece of code unless a global flag becomes **TRUE**. The threads will not share any data, with the exception of the global flag. I am wondering if the best practice would be to add a mutex for the flag.

To keep this question simple, I will resort to the following trivial example: assume that you are trying to find whether a large vector contains a given integer, and you want to split the search between several threads. There is a global variable whose initial value is **FALSE**. If one of the threads finds the integer, it should set the flag to **TRUE** and all the threads should stop afterwards (it is ok if some threads execute a few extra operations until they realize the flag has changed).

The following code does that (I apologize for the race condition over cout, but I want to keep the code short). It creates a large vector filled with 500, replaces one of the 500 with a 100, and implements the search procedure.

The code compiles and seems to work, but I am wondering if something can go wrong with the read/write of the flag at some point. I am wondering if I should add a mutex for the flag variable. I am hesitant because (1) for the most part the threads will only read the value of the flag, (2) the flag will only change once (it will never change back to false), (3) the value of the flag does not change the data within the threads execution (it does nothing besides besides stoping them) (4) it is Ok if the threads continue for a few iterations.

Should I perhaps only add a mutex lock for the writing part in the functor (flag=true)?

```
vector <int> a;
bool flag = false;
int size = 100000000

class Fctor {
    int s;
    int t;
 public:
    Fctor(int s, int t) : s(s), t(t) {}
    \\ finds if there is a 100 in the vector between positions s and t
    void operator()() { 
        int i = 0;
        for (i = s; i < t; i++) {
            if (flag == true) break;
            if (a[i] == 100) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    cout << s << " " << t << " " << flag << " " << i << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {

    a = vector<int> (8 * size, 500); \\creates a vector filled with 500
    a[2*size+1] = 100; // This position will have a 100
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin_time = 
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int cores = 4;
    vector<std::thread> threads;
    int num = 8/cores;
    int s = 0;
    int t = num * size;
    Fctor fctor(s, t);
    std::thread th(fctor);
    threads.push_back(std::move(th));

    for (int i = 1; i < cores; i++) {
            int s1 = i * num * size+1;
            int t1 = (i+1) * num * size;
            Fctor fctor1(s1, t1);
            std::thread th1(fctor1);
            threads.push_back(std::move(th1));
    }
    for (std::thread& th : threads) {
            th.join();
    }

    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end_time = 
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> time_span = 
        chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double> >(end_time - 
        begin_time);
    cout << "Found in: "<< time_span.count() << " seconds. \n";
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: See `std::atomic` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Answer (score 0):

Setting the flag as atomic does the job